# Example of Pytorch Checkpointed Model Zoo

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, training

I am interested in the training dynamics of neural networks and would like to access a selection of trained (or more specifically partially trained) networks over the course of their training without having to train them all myself. I wondered if there is some repo or Pytorch function that would give me access to a variety of models at various points throughout their training procedure